# Cell editing breaks if editor is used quickly, bug in ExtJS / Chrome

Tags: javascript, extjs

Working with ExtJS (7) using modular windows (not React), I've recently encountered a bug where editing a cell too quickly before the rendering or backend functions finish SOMETIMES will create a scenario where the given editor for a column vanishes from the `dom` property of the editor. Stepping through the core ExtJS code was necessary to find this snippet which didn't provide any solutions:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432392

The problem being, once ExtJS loses this dom element, I haven't found a way to get it to refresh or replace it without wiping the entire grid and that's obviously unacceptable for usability reasons. The problem is in the `CellEditing.js` file of `classic/grid/plugin/CellEditing.js` area when it calls the line (roughly line #410 ish):

`p = editor.el.dom.parentNode;`

This throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at ctor.activateCell (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:123916:30)
    at ctor.activateCell (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:112576:35)
    at ctor.setActionableMode (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:112771:27)
    at ctor.setActionableMode (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:108918:41)
    at ctor.onCellClick (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:123793:15)
    at ctor.fire (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:11634:32)
    at ctor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:12125:41)
    at ctor.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:37543:45)
    at b.doFireEvent (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:33414:19)
    at ctor.fireEventArgs (app.js?_dc=20230104061611:formatted:12051:23)
```

Since `dom` is somehow dropped (I have been unable to figure out why exactly dom is dropped other than the aforementioned bug link), this throws a null pointer and blows up the app. Anything after this point fails to work properly and the whole page must be refreshed.

This is not an easily reproducible bug, but the slower the computer and connection, the more likely it is to pop up. I reproduce it manually by setting a breakpoint right before the `p = editor.el.dom.parentNode;` line and then making whatever attempts in the code that I can think of.

The full context of this error occurs withing the `activateCell` method on in the `CellEditing.js` class. I've overriden the class in hopes of making a patch, and can make changes there if anyone has a solution!

I've tried wrapping this in a try/catch block, I've tried to add a block to re-render the editor if the dom is missing, I've tried to destroy the editor and rebuild it in the cached editor section, and all of them have failed with various levels of still being pretty broken such as:

```
Error.js?_dc=1672869371981:103 Uncaught Error: Missing DOM node in element garbage collection: celleditor-1529
    at new Ext.Error (Error.js?_dc=1672869371981:103:21)
    at Function.raise (Error.js?_dc=1672869371981:180:23)
    at Ext.raise (Error.js?_dc=1672869371981:269:21)
    at constructor.collect (GarbageCollector.js?_dc=1672869371980:67:21)
    at constructor.resume (GarbageCollector.js?_dc=1672869371980:160:16)
    at constructor.onTouchEnd (Gesture.js?_dc=1672869371981:588:54)
    at constructor.publishDelegatedDomEvent (Gesture.js?_dc=1672869371981:457:33)
    at constructor.doDelegatedEvent (Dom.js?_dc=1672869371981:506:16)
    at constructor.onDelegatedEvent (Dom.js?_dc=1672869371981:487:18)
```

Comment: I seem to have same issue, on a application recently migrated from Extjs 4 to 7.5.1. Extjs 4 had no issue, what version are you using?